# Process cannot execute more than 3 functions at the same time

Tags: python

I have script.py whose aim is to process up to 3 trajectory files (.gro), which the user has a choice on how many to analyze in one execution of the script. I also have up to 5 functions (analysis types) which the user has a choice on how many to input on the terminal:

> python script.py -f traj1.gro,traj2.gro,traj3.gro -a analysis1,analysis2,analysis3 -o results

Each analysis type has its own function, and all traj files entered by the user is stored in a list: `analysistypes` . One by one, each traj file is processed, but all analysis types need to happen simultaneously, so I used Process somewhere in my code

```
files = [] #['traj1.gro','traj2.gro','traj3.gro']
analysistypes = [] #['analysis1','analysis2','analysis3']
results = '' (everything from the terminal stored using sys.argv)

def analysis1(ffile):
    outfile1 = '%s_outfile1_%s.xvg'%(results, ffile[:-4])
    with open('%s'%outfile1, 'w') as out:
            out.write('@    TITLE "analysis1"')
            out.write('\n')
    with open(ffile, 'rb') as fi:
        ...do something
        with open('%s'%outfile1, 'a') as out: #outfile1 is output file for analysis 1
            for something...
            ...do something
                        out.write('\n')
                        out.write(info)

def analysis2(ffile):
    (similar to above, produces output file with info)

... and so on for the other analyses

def runAll(fns,i):
    proc = []
    for fnName in fns:
        fn = globals()[fnName]
        p = Process(target=fn, args=(i,))
        p.start()
        proc.append(p)
    for p in proc:
        p.join()

for ffile in files:

    runAll(analysistypes,ffile)

    ... rest of the code
```

I am expecting an output file for each analysis type, for each traj file. In this case I need 3 output files for each traj file (I have 3) so a total of 9 output files. THIS WORKS PERFECTLY FINE.

The problem is if I start to attempt to try 4 analysis types. One output file would always be blank. It's there and it has a title, at least, but the data is simply not there. I am 100 % certain that it is not a problem of the function because I have tried each separately a million times and it only messes up when I try to run 4 at the same time. It has even gotten to a point when an error message says that:

> .... got 5 columns instead of 5

but that is besides the point. The function that the terminal "blames" is not consistent and would change each time. Also, when I tried 5 at the same time, one output file would be blank, one would be half complete, while the others would be completely fine.

(I also tried to put only 1 traj file and 5 analysis types, got the same result.)

I also looked up solutions online and tried another way:

I replaced the runAll inside the for loop with this one:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    procs = []
    for ana in analysistypes:
        anaa = globals()[ana]
        procs.append(Process(target=anaa, args=(ffile,)))
    map(lambda x: x.start(), procs)
    map(lambda x: x.join(), procs)
```

but it still doesn't work and I am getting the same results. I am suspecting the file size of each trajectory file, which is 12 GB each. I am using Mac, operating system is Ubuntu and hard drive space is 120 GB, and I've used up 55%. Can the file size be to blame here?